# Allocate memory struct of a struct matrix

Tags: c, matrix, struct

My struct is:

```
typedef struct grafo GRAFO;
struct aresta {

    int adj; 
    float peso;
};

struct grafo {
    struct aresta **arestas;
};
```

I can't manage to malloc the matrix arestas like that:

```
GRAFO *grafo_aux = (GRAFO*) malloc(sizeof(GRAFO));
grafo_aux->arestas = malloc(num_vert * sizeof(struct aresta*));
```

What is the correct code? Thank you!

Comment: Why is `arestas` in `grafo` a double pointer? There is no need for that I think

Comment: How do you know it's not right?  See [mcve]

Comment: @BarthyB. - why do you say that? We have no knowledge of the OP's problem/soution.

Comment: @BarthyB. the use of `num_vert` in the `malloc` for `arestas` means its probably meant to be a list.

Comment: @Ben the title says matrix which sound more like an array than a list to me. And for that you don't need a double pointer afaik. But I'm just guessing and shouldn't do that, i'm out of the discussion.

Comment: Hello, the `num_vert `is variable that i`ll receive from a file, so I made a global variable. And `arestas**` is a double pointer because I need a matrix of edges. Before dynamically allocating my matrix `arestas**`, it was `struct aresta arestas[MAX][MAX]`. But now I need to receive `MAX` from a file, so I created the global variable `num_vert`. All my code is ready, except for this. I dont know how to use malloc for a struct of a struct. I think now its a bit more clear why I coded like that. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: try this; 
grafo_aux->arestas = malloc(num_vert * sizeof *grafo_aux->arestas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to allocate a `num_vert*n` matrix (where `num_vert` and `n` are meant to be read from file) you should perhaps finish the allocation job before attempting to populate the matrix with some values…

```
GRAFO *grafo_aux = (GRAFO*) malloc(sizeof(GRAFO));
grafo_aux->arestas = malloc(num_vert * sizeof(struct aresta*));

for ( i = 0 ; i < num_vert ; i++ ){
   grafo_aux->arestas[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(struct aresta));//allocate
   for( j = 0 ; j < n ; j++ ){
      grafo_aux->arestas[i][j].adj  = some_int_value;   //populate
      grafo_aux->arestas[i][j].peso = some_float_value; //populate
      }
}
```

Comment: I mixed your code with what I had in here and it worked perfectly! It's really tricky to work with structs, thank you very much for teaching properly!

Comment: @Louise Martins, two dimensional arrays have to be allocated in both dimensions. Good luck!